# AngularJs Model changes don't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model that I want to be editable, but for some reason **nothing change, the textbox doesn't show up and the model is not being updated** when using `ng-view`.

I can see the function `enableEditor()` being called using `console.log`.

If I write it inline instead of `ng-view` in the *index.html* without the *profile.html* everything works perfectly.

here are the files:

**app.js**

```
var proGamersApp = angular.module('proGamersApp', ['ngResource']).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: 'ProfileController', templateUrl: '/app/partials/profile.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

var ProfileController = function ($scope) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.title = 'first title';
    };

    $scope.init();
    $scope.enableEditor = function () {
        console.log('enableEditor()')
        $scope.editorEnabled = true;
        $scope.editableTitle = 'second title';
        $scope.title = 'second title';
    };

     ...
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="proGamersApp">
<head>
    <title>Pro Gamers</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**profile.html**

```
 <div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
        {{title}}
      <a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit title</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="editorEnabled">
        <input ng-model="title" ng-show="editorEnabled">
        <a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>
        or
      <a href="#" ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.
    </div>
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Add `target=_self` to your links, the `#` at the end is probably refreshing the page since it's adding your link.

Comment: I've replaced the href="#" with href="target=_self" and I see the page changes and the textbox shows up, but after a blink of an eye it changes back to nothing. if i remove the href attribute of the a element it doesn't looks like a link but it do the job. Do you know what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Yep, you shouldn't be using anchors that target nothing, instead use a span with proper CSS styling to make it look like a link (I know, using blank links is tempting and easier, but you run into issues like this)

Comment: Added an answer along with some CSS to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is adding to your address, causing the router to refresh the page and wack all your $scope vars. Instead of using blank anchors, use a span styled like an anchor:

```
span:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

This only gives the cursor the pointer finger, customize the colors as you wish. Per your comments as well, don't add the `target=_self` to the href, add it after:

```
<a href="#" target=_self ng-click="save()">Save</a> //prevent address bar change
```

As I said before though, use spans instead.

Comment: the 'target=_self' doesn't fix the a element problem even if I put it the way you show in your example, the href should be either empty or missing in order to prevent page reload so you might want to remove it from the answer.

The span solution, however, did the job.
I learn from it for further use, since I didn't used the span element at all up to now.